# Why does this error appears when i'm trying to add a new row?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

When I run this code

```
else
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[14].Value.ToString() != "Não")
    {
        if (dataGridView2.ColumnCount >= 1)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["Id_Veiculo"].Value == null)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(N_Vender, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value, nomeC);

                    int a;

                    a = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text);
                    string s = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[17].Value.ToString();
                    int b = int.Parse(s);

                    (bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text) = Convert.ToString(a + b);
                    break;
                }
                else if (Id_Veiculo == (int)row.Cells["Id_Veiculo"].Value)
                {
                    //dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells[14].Value = (int)(dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value) + 1;

                    int a;
                    a = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text);

                    string s = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[17].Value.ToString();

                    int b = int.Parse(s);

                    (bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text) = Convert.ToString(a + b);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[14].Value = "Não";
    }
}
```

When I press a row from datagridview1, it was suppossed to create a new row in `datagridview2` with some information on `datagridview1`. But an error appears on `dataGridView2.Rows.Add`, and I have no idea what to do about it.

I'm trying to add a row to datagridview2

https://gyazo.com/eaeb5a163b61bb1bef128a726712d2c6

Comment: Please post the error message (in english). It should describe the problem.

Comment: Don't do this; bind the datagridviews to datatables and push rows into the tables instead